# Is this a valid shell sed command and what does it do?

Tags: shell, sed

```
sed 's/\([ab]\)\([ab]\)./\2\1x/g' file.txt
```

My understanding is:
in file.txt, find any string start with either 'a' or 'b', followed by either an 'a' or a 'b', followed by any ONE char (say 'abc'), and replace it with the string 1st, and 2nd char switched palce, and 3rd char is x ('bax'). Is the syntax of the command correct? and am I correct?

Comment: Definitely take Jefromi's suggestion and try it on a sample file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are correct, except for the start part. This will match characters anywhere in the string, as many times as possible, so you end up with substitutions like this:

```
"123ab1" to "123bax"
"1234ab" to "1234ab"
"ab1ba2" to "baxabx"
"bbaabb" to "bbxbax"
```

What you may want to do is anchor it to the start of the string with the caret character, like this:

```
s/^\([ab]\)\([ab]\)./\2\1x/g
```

Giving:

```
"abc123" to "bax123"
"123abc" to "123abc"
```

Answer (score 2):

Yep, you are - note that the 'g' on the end means it'll make the substitution as many times as it can on every line.  Any reason you couldn't just try it and see?